# Single convolution layer neural network

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I want a classifier predicting either image is noised (randomly generated) or monochromatic. For this purpose I followed [this](https://medium.com/@michaeldelsole/a-single-layer-artificial-neural-network-in-20-lines-of-python-ae34b47e5fef) article. The idea is to use 1 conv layer to make a prediction on 2x2 image with a single 2x2 filter without frameworks like pytorch, tensorflow. My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# generates random or monochromatic image
def generate_image(label, size=2):
    if not label:
        return np.array(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=256, size=(size,size)).astype(int).flatten())/255
    else:
        intencity = random.randrange(256)
        return np.array(np.full((size, size), intencity).flatten())/255 

batch = 10
synaptic_weights = np.random.random((4,1))
for iteration in range(1000):
    y = np.array([np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(batch,))]).T
    x = np.array([generate_image(label=label) for label in y])
    z = np.dot(x, synaptic_weights)
    sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    error = (y - sigmoid)
    sigmoidDerivative = sigmoid * (1 - sigmoid)
    synaptic_weights += np.dot(x.T, error*sigmoidDerivative)

# testing
y = np.array([np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10,))]).T
x = np.array([generate_image(label=label) for label in y])
for each_x, each_y in zip(x,y):
    print("Considering new situation: {}, label {}".format(each_x, each_y))
    newZ = np.dot(np.array(each_x), synaptic_weights)
    activationOutput = 1/(1+np.exp(-newZ))
    print(activationOutput)
```

However the testing iteration output is wrong. I also tried to use MSE (then *synaptic_weights -= lrate*np.dot(x.T, errorsigmoidDerivative*) but it leads to no improvement.

**The testing output is the following:**

```
Considering new situation: [0.66666667 0.66666667 0.66666667 0.66666667], label [1]
[0.90545359]
Considering new situation: [0.70196078 0.70196078 0.70196078 0.70196078], label [1]
[0.91520858]
Considering new situation: [0.69019608 0.76078431 0.84313725 0.79215686], label [0]
[0.9363774]
Considering new situation: [0.12156863 0.21568627 0.48235294 0.03137255], label [0]
[0.70342397]
Considering new situation: [0.73333333 0.34509804 0.75294118 0.81176471], label [0]
[0.91804572]
Considering new situation: [0.81568627 0.81568627 0.81568627 0.81568627], label [1]
[0.9407201]
Considering new situation: [0.94901961 0.94901961 0.94901961 0.94901961], label [1]
[0.96144103]
Considering new situation: [0.61960784 0.61960784 0.61960784 0.61960784], label [1]
[0.89088977]
Considering new situation: [0.03921569 0.48627451 0.39215686 0.17647059], label [0]
[0.72496681]
Considering new situation: [0.09803922 0.34509804 0.89019608 0.30980392], label [0]
[0.85380137]
```

So, prediction is not aligned with ground-truth.

I expect my classifier to work correctly on both random and monochromatic images. I also tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466822/single-layer-neural-network-for-and-logic-gate-python) source changed for my purpose as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x,derivative=False):
    if(derivative==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

batch = 100000
np.random.seed(1)
weights = np.random.randn(1, 4)

y = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(batch,)))
x = np.array([generate_image(label=label) for label in y])
training = np.array([[np.array(each_x).reshape(1, -1), each_y] for each_x, each_y in zip(x,y.copy())])

for iter in range(training.shape[0]):
#forwardPropagation:
        a_layer1 = training[iter][0]
        z_layer2 = np.dot(weights,a_layer1.reshape(-1, 1))
        a_layer2 = sigmoid(z_layer2)
        hypothesis_theta = a_layer2

#backPropagation:
        delta_neuron1_layer2 =  (a_layer2 - training[iter][1] ) * sigmoid(a_layer2 , derivative=True)
        Delta_neuron1_layer2 = np.dot(delta_neuron1_layer2 , a_layer1)
        update = Delta_neuron1_layer2
        weights = weights - update 


y = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10,)))
x = np.array([generate_image(label=label) for label in y])
for each_x, each_y in zip(x,y):
    print("Considering new situation: {}, label {}".format(each_x, each_y))
    print(sigmoid(np.dot(weights,each_x.reshape(-1, 1))))
```

**But it also does not work as it should and the output is following:**

```
Considering new situation: [0.08627451 0.79215686 0.59215686 0.11764706], label 0
[[0.41410472]]
Considering new situation: [0.59215686 0.59215686 0.59215686 0.59215686], label 1
[[0.27783699]]
Considering new situation: [0.83529412 0.90196078 0.57254902 0.93333333], label 0
[[0.21860375]]
Considering new situation: [0.8745098  0.54509804 0.05882353 0.24705882], label 0
[[0.33548392]]
Considering new situation: [0.8        0.6745098  0.49803922 0.59215686], label 0
[[0.26199003]]
Considering new situation: [0.17254902 0.74117647 0.21960784 0.76862745], label 0
[[0.35358107]]
Considering new situation: [0.04705882 0.58823529 0.43921569 1.        ], label 0
[[0.31572008]]
Considering new situation: [0.21176471 0.21176471 0.21176471 0.21176471], label 1
[[0.41542074]]
Considering new situation: [0.46666667 0.43921569 0.82352941 0.25490196], label 0
[[0.30943309]]
Considering new situation: [0.38823529 0.88235294 0.42745098 0.63921569], label 0
[[0.32000279]]
```

As I see the prediction is again far from label.

Comment: You need to be very specific on "the output is wrong" or "does not work as it should", you need to tell us what outputs you see.

Comment: Thank you. Updated with the output results.

Comment: Maybe try using different batch sizes or training iterations, maybe you're not training enough or you could be overfitting the data, maybe your model is doing well on training set, but doing worst on test set, means your model is not learning enough. try oncrease features too, play with batch_size, and also with layers maybe.